How to validate dates in JSF?
I'm using JSF Mojarra 2.3.17 and JRE 21.
My bean has a LocalDate variable and the following JSF page:
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date1flt}" pt:type="date">
  <f:convertDateTime type="localDate" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</h:inputText>

Why does it not have some sort of error message for "2024-06-31" when it's not a valid date (30 days in June). Instead, it sets the bean variable to null.
If I try LocalDate.of(2024, 6, 31); I get java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'JUNE 31', which is good, but nothing if I use JSF.
